# A sphere rolling up an inclined plane

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

If a sphere executing pure rolling motion up an inclined plane then we can say that the frictional force acting on it is zero. We can also conserve momentum about the centre of the sphere as net torque acting on it is zero . 
After some time the sphere will stop (conserving energy) and it's angular as well as translational velocity will become zero(at the topmost point). Since it's angular velocity has become zero this means its initial angular momentum should have also been zero by applying conservation of momentum but this is not true. So aren't these two things contradicting each other.
And also as the sphere will move upwards it will lose its kinteic energy and in turn losing its velocity and angular momentum. So isn't the momentum being reduced and not remaining conserved? Can anyone explain me where am I going wrong

Comment: frictional force is not $0$,

Comment: But the frictional force acting on the body is zero

Comment: @ PSN03 that's not true if friction becomes $0$ how can sphere roll

Comment: Why wouldn't it roll? Moreover if friction will act then it would generate a torque.

Comment: it wouldn't role purely as force would act on COM of body making it to deaccelerate with different acceleration as that of its end which is in contact with inclined plane

Comment: U mean to say that even the angular momentum won't be conserved in this case...right?

Comment: yes but energy would  be conserved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107508/discussion-between-psn03-and-maverick).

Comment: As others have already pointed out, it is not a correct assumption that "*the frictional force acting on it is zero*". There is no *kinetic* friction, but there is a *static friction* at the contact point. That static friction prevents the contact point from sliding - and it *would* otherwise slide, since gravity pulls. Thus, the static friction force always points upwards, regardless of rolling direction.

Comment: Another way to know that a static friction force must be present is to consider that without it, there would be no torque to slow down the angular speed. The ball would never stop spinning, not even when it reaches the top of it's translational motion and momentarily has a (translational) speed of zero.

Comment: "the frictional force acting on it is zero" sorry but I can't see why

Comment: @Steeven thanks a lot....I was wrong...thanks a lot for clearing my doubt :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sphere is rolling up the incline, then there is a static friction force acting on the sphere from the surface of the incline.  This force is acting up the surface and produces a torque vector which is directed opposite to the angular velocity vector.  The resulting loss of angular velocity must match the corresponding loss of linear velocity.  Linear and angular kinetic energy are converted to gravitational potential energy.  Because of the external forces and torque, linear and angular momentum are not conserved.

Answer (score 2):

The conservation laws hold for isolated systems. The sphere is interacting with the slope, hence with Earth. The total momentum and angular momentum of sphere plus Earth is conserved.

Comment: Ohk.... That's something interesting. Does this mean that the slope is also gaining some momentum? If it is doing so then why aren't we able to see it?

Comment: You do not observer it if the slope is attached to something very big and heavy,  usually Earth. Any variation in the momentum and angular momentum of Earth of this magnitude is too tiny to observe.

Comment: Ohk...thanks a lot. By the way will there be frictional force acting on the sphere?